# ADO Entity Builder won't generate class for table with just foreign keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado

I have a SQL table that has two foreign keys and when I run Entity Data Model Wizard and select Code First from database, and then create the tables, my table won't show up as a class. It generates something in the primary model class that looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Categories)
    .WithMany(e => e.Users)
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("UserCategory").MapLeftKey("UserID").MapRightKey("ID"));
```

But I don't know how to use that to add or delete from that table, since it won't show up as a class when I'm coding.

My tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE [User] 
(
    ID NVARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(255),
    JoinDate DATETIME,
    ZipCode VARCHAR(25),
    SearchRadius INT,
    LoginToBusinessSide BIT
);

/*The categories businesses can fall under. */
CREATE TABLE Category 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
);

/*The categories chosen by a specific user to get notified of*/
CREATE TABLE UserCategory 
(
    ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Category(ID),
    UserID NVARCHAR(128) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [User](ID),
    CONSTRAINT PK_UserCategory PRIMARY KEY (ID, UserID)
);
```

How do I get `UserCategory` to show up as its own class, so I can easily access it?

I want to be able to just access it like every other class:

```
db.UserCategories.ID =
```

How can I

Comment: Are you sure you want it as a separate class? The generator assumes it's a many-to-many table so it removes it from the model. Instead, it creates `ICollection<B>` in `A` and `ICollection<A>` in `B`. You can change this manually, not sure if there's a switch to control that. However, the default setup is correct.

Comment: So if the default setup is correct, how do I go about accessing it? Because I can't just access my database class with . notation, the table doesn't appear.

Comment: What model classes are generated?

Comment: If I do them all, all get generated except UserCategory.

Comment: I guess you missed my first comment. The `UserCategory` is not there. Instead, you have `Categories` in `User` class and `Users` in `Category` class.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I think maybe I see. When I create a User class, I can access the categories. But then I seem to be asking the wrong question. What I really need is a linking table, where I can sort through and add new objects into the database easily. 

If i add an Identity field, the table then shows up and I can access it as its own class. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can sort and add new objects easily, still without the linking table.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Can you provide an example of adding objects? I am still not understanding.

Comment: `var category = new Category(); user.Categories.Add( category ); var user = new User(); category.Users.Add( user );` it should be that simple. In this example, I add a user to a category and then, a category to a user. Two independent examples.

Answer (score 0):

ADO doesn't create a class for my many to many table, but I can still access it. To add new categories to it, I use this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < categories.Length; ++i)
{
   var user = db.Users.Find(thisUser.ID);
   var cat = db.Categories.Find(categories[i]);
   user.Categories.Add(cat);
}
```

I have to an active connection to both tables that the foreign keys are linked to, and then when I add one to the Categories table, it goes to the correct place.

If you understand exactly why this works, or if there's a better way, please do comment.